# Spark scala remove columns containing only null values

Tags: scala, null, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to remove the columns of a spark dataFrame that contain only null values ?
(I am using scala and Spark 1.6.2)

At the moment I am doing this:

```
var validCols: List[String] = List()
for (col <- df_filtered.columns){
  val count = df_filtered
    .select(col)
    .distinct
    .count
  println(col, count)
  if (count >= 2){
    validCols ++= List(col)
  }
}
```

to build the list of column containing at least two distinct values, and then use it in a select().

Thank you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove NULL columns in Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45324762/remove-null-columns-in-spark-sql)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and i came up with a similar solution in Java. In my opinion there is no other way of doing it at the moment.

```
for (String column:df.columns()){
    long count = df.select(column).distinct().count();

    if(count == 1 && df.select(column).first().isNullAt(0)){
        df = df.drop(column);
    }
}
```

I'm dropping all columns containing exactly one distinct value and which first value is null. This way I can be sure that i don't drop columns where all values are the same but not null.

Comment: Small correction, there is a syntax error of missing curly bracket in for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a scala example to remove null columns that only queries that data once (faster):

```
def removeNullColumns(df:DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    var dfNoNulls = df
    val exprs = df.columns.map((_ -> "count")).toMap
    val cnts = df.agg(exprs).first
    for(c <- df.columns) {
        val uses = cnts.getAs[Long]("count("+c+")")
        if ( uses == 0 ) {
            dfNoNulls = dfNoNulls.drop(c)
        }
    }
    return dfNoNulls
}
```

Comment: Use of `var` and `return`: not idiomatic Scala.

Comment: @jwvh The `return` keyword can easily be removed. Avoiding using a `var` would mean using `.select()` instead of `.drop()` since the latter doesn't support arrays. IMHO, neither change make it any more readable.

Answer (score 1):

A more idiomatic version of @swdev answer:

```
private def removeNullColumns(df:DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  val exprs = df.columns.map((_ -> "count")).toMap
  val cnts = df.agg(exprs).first
  df.columns
    .filter(c => cnts.getAs[Long]("count("+c+")") == 0)
    .foldLeft(df)((df, col) => df.drop(col))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dataframe is of reasonable size, I write it as json then reload it. The dynamic schema will ignore null columns and you'd have a lighter dataframe.

scala snippet:

```scala
originalDataFrame.write(tempJsonPath)
val lightDataFrame = spark.read.json(tempJsonPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

here's @timo-strotmann solution in pySpark syntax:

```py
for column in df.columns:
    count = df.select(column).distinct().count()
    if count == 1 and df.first()[column] is None:
        df = df.drop(column)
```