# How to show only relevant columns from Spark's DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a large JSON file with 432 key-value pairs and many rows of such data. That data is loaded pretty well, however when I want to use df.show() to display 20 items I see a bunch of nulls. The file is quite sparse. It's very hard to make something out of it.  What would be nice is to drop columns that have only nulls for 20 rows, however, given that I have a lot of key-value pairs it's hard to do manually.  Is there a way to detect in Spark's dataframe what columns contain only nulls and drop them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove NULL columns in Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45324762/remove-null-columns-in-spark-sql)

Comment: Can you show the output of "df.show() to display 20 items with a bunch of nulls."? How many rows do you work with? Asking for "drop columns that have only nulls for 20 rows" has little to no need for Spark as there are simply 20 rows in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below, for more info, [referred_question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48110448/how-to-get-column-names-with-all-values-null)

```
scala> val df = Seq((1,2,null),(3,4,null),(5,6,null),(7,8,"9")).toDF("a","b","c")

scala> df.show
+---+---+----+
|  a|  b|   c|
+---+---+----+
|  1|  2|null|
|  3|  4|null|
|  5|  6|null|
|  7|  8|   9|
+---+---+----+

scala> val dfl = df.limit(3) //limiting the number of rows you need, in your case it is 20

scala> val col_names = dfl.select(dfl.columns.map(x => count(col(x)).alias(x)):_*).first.toSeq.zipWithIndex.filter(x => x._1.toString.toInt > 0).map(_._2).map(x => dfl.columns(x)).map(x => col(x)) // this will give you column names which is having not null values
col_names: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = ArrayBuffer(a, b)

scala> dfl.select(col_names : _*).show
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  3|  4|
|  5|  6|
+---+---+
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Sathiyan's idea, but using the columnname in the count() itself.

```
scala>  val df = Seq((1,2,null),(3,4,null),(5,6,null)).toDF("a","b","c")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, b: int ... 1 more field]

scala> df.show
+---+---+----+
|  a|  b|   c|
+---+---+----+
|  1|  2|null|
|  3|  4|null|
|  5|  6|null|
+---+---+----+


scala> val notnull_cols = df.select(df.columns.map(x=>concat_ws("=",first(lit(x)),count(col(x)))):_*).first.toSeq.map(_.toString).filter(!_.contains("=0")).map( x=>col(x.split("=")(0)) )
notnull_cols: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = ArrayBuffer(a, b)

scala> df.select(notnull_cols:_*).show
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  3|  4|
|  5|  6|
+---+---+
```

The intermediate results shows the count along with column names

```
scala> df.select(df.columns.map(x=>concat_ws("=",first(lit(x)),count(col(x))).as(x+"_nullcount")):_*).show
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|a_nullcount|b_nullcount|c_nullcount|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|        a=3|        b=3|        c=0|
+-----------+---------- -+-----------+


scala>
```